# Flutter - I want to use GestureDetector rather than button

Tags: flutter, screenshot, gesturedetector

The current code uses a button to generate a screenshot, but I would like to use a GestureDetector rather than a button to generate the screenshot.

If you put GestureDetector in the original code, the captured screen should be created at the bottom, but it is not created. I would be grateful if you could help me by explaining it with code.

Currently, the capture is created only when the yellow button is pressed and the image appears at the bottom, but I want to use the GestureDetector in a black container to produce the same result as the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to wrap with GestureDetector widget and
I got a result what you expected.

Would you let me know how or where use GestureDetector?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage_1(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage_1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePage_1State createState() => _MyHomePage_1State();
}

class _MyHomePage_1State extends State<MyHomePage_1> {
  GlobalKey _globalKey = GlobalKey();
  var _bytes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Screenshot Example")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 250,
                  height: 250,
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onLongPress: () async {
                          final render = (_globalKey.currentContext
                              .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary);
                          final imageBytes = (await (await render.toImage())
                                  .toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png))
                              .buffer
                              .asUint8List();
                          setState(() {
                            _bytes = imageBytes;
                          });
                        },
                        child: RepaintBoundary(
                          key: _globalKey,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            color: Colors.black87,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),

          /// display
          if (_bytes != null) Image.memory(_bytes, width: 250),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Excuse me, but could you please take a look at the other questions I have posted? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732796/flutter-dragging-a-screenshot

Comment: @이수빈 Did you solve requested post question?

Comment: Yes! Solved it in a few hours! thank you:)

Comment: I posted a new question, can you help?

Comment: @이수빈 I'll check that.